# Excel VBA data scrape - not all data being pulled

Tags: excel, vba

I posted a similar question recently, but I've been able to successfully scrape some data from webpages since then. However, I've run into a problem. When trying to scrape from this page: https://www.scpcn.ca/clinics

I'm trying to get addresses and clinic names, however, when I use this code I only get the first page. It's also outputting two of each clinics on the first page but no addresses.

Even weirder is that it worked once, pulling all the clinics and about half the addresses, when I deleted this and tried to run again I only got the first 10 clinics and that's where its at now.

I thought the issue was that the page wasn't waiting long enough so I added a wait timer but that didn't seem to do anything.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetSouthClinicData()

    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim clinicEle As Object
    Dim clinicAdd As Object

    Dim clinicName As String
    Dim clinicAddress As String
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim x As Integer

    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    objIE.Visible = True

    objIE.Navigate "https://www.scpcn.ca/clinics"
    While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:5"))

    y = 2

    For Each clinicEle In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("clinic-title")
        clinicName = clinicEle.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).innerText
        Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & y).Value = clinicName
        y = y + 1
    Next

    x = 2
        For Each clinicEle In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("toggle-address clinic-address")
        clinicAddress = clinicEle.getElementsByTagName("br")(0).innerText
        Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B" & x).Value = clinicAddress
        x = x + 1
    Next

    objIE.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Where are you determining the number of pages and looping them?

Comment: When I was clicking through the pages on the website, the URL doesn't change so I thought it would all be able to be pulled from the first page. However, my main question is why am I pulling two clinic names and no addresses? Is it something to do with the fact that the addresses are hidden?

Comment: I can't load that page for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following which returns nodeLists based on class and then indexing in

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.scpcn.ca/clinics", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        Dim names As Object, addresses As Object, i As Long
        Set names = html.querySelectorAll(".clinic-title")
        Set addresses = html.querySelectorAll(".clinic-address")
        For i = 0 To names.Length - 1
            With ActiveSheet
                .Cells(i + 1, 1) = names.item(i).innerText
                .Cells(i + 1, 2) = addresses.item(i).innerText
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```